# SQL DATABASE select something with something =x value and max or an other thing

Tags: sql

I have a table 'users'

**username  | play | time**

and i want to select the username where `play=1 and time is max` .

Comment: `select username,play,max(time) from table where play=1 group by username,play`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select username from users
       where play=1 and time in(select max(time) from users)
```

Comment: using * is a bad practice.

Comment: It might has duplicates in max(time) and IN would cause performance problems in large tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
select username from users where play=1 and time in(select max(time) from users)
```

Comment: It might has duplicates in max(time) and IN would cause performance problems in large tables.